# How do I change the alignment of the Numbers/Bullets of a list using only HTML?

Tags: html

[image: Screenshot of current output]

"A, B, C" or "2, 3, 4" are supposed be with the text. For example: "A. Home", without the huge gap; the total alignment should be centre. I cannot use CSS: an HTML only solution is required. Here is the code:

```html
<body bgcolor="gray" align="center">
  <ol type="A" Title="Alphabet Type">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

What should I do?

Comment: your body contain `text-align:center`, that is inherited by `ul, li`.

Comment: You are already using `CSS` by providing `style` attribute.  What styling  you want to achieve is not possible without CSS. Right now you can remove `text-align:center;` to get what you want

Comment: Ow thanks, I edited to HTML only now. Well if not possible without CSS then ok, you can show me how to do it with CSS. And removing text alignment arribute would set the alignment to left. But I want it in center.

Comment: Remove the [align="center"] from body tag. Enclose your <ol> with a centered div, something like: <div align="center"><ol>....</ol></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the `ol` an inline-block, so that it's centered and doesn't stretch the whole parent width.
2. Put the indexes inside so that they don't show one under the other to the left.

```html
<body bgcolor="gray" align="center">
  <ol type="A" Title="Alphabet Type" style="display: inline-block;list-style-position:inside;">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

or maybe you want them aligned

```html
<body bgcolor="gray" align="center">
  <ol type="A" Title="Alphabet Type" style="display: inline-block;" align="left">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: Umm....Just to understand the use of inline-block, Could you please tell me how that "display: inline-block" is helping here if it's convenient for you?

Comment: @FarhanFuad Short story: It makes a whole "block", in your case the "OL" behave like an inline item (a single letter for example). By default "OL" elements are blocks and take up the whole width of the parent. Long story: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html